# $\lim_{x \to a}(x-a) = 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I’m taking calculus at mooculus, and the professor, as an intermediate step to a problem, wrote down $$\lim_{x\to a} \:(x-a) =0$$. I can’t seem to get a proper intuition for this. Can you help me to understand this concept, as I thought I had a grip on limits. Why does this equal zero?

Comment: Are you sure it's not $x\rightarrow 0$ rather than $x\rightarrow a$? Because the way it is written it's wrong.

Comment: @yanko Sorry. Should be $(x-a)$

Comment: Now It make sense...

Comment: If not zero what should it be based on your grasp of limits? If you try to think a bit you will be convinced that it is zero. The idea of limit is not as difficult as most people would want to you believe and questions such as these are almost trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Intuition**:

As $x$ gets closer and closer to $a$, $x-a$ gets closer and closer to $0$.

**Explicit example**:

Now let say $a$ is equal to $1$.

Consider some numbers $x_n$ that gets closer and closer to $1$, say $x_1=0.9$, $x_2=0.99$, $x_3=0.999$.

Try to compute $x_1-1$, $x_2-1$, $x_3-1$.

**Definition**: 
Given any $\epsilon > 0$, can you find $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-a|< \delta \implies  |x-a| < \epsilon$?

If you can find such a $\delta$, then that is the meaning of the limit statement.

Comment: Yes. I understand the syntax already, but just knowing syntactically does not help me gain a profound intuition as to why this is the answer. Why is this equal to 0?

Comment: Suppose $x=a+1$. Then $x-a=1$.
Suppose $x=a+0.1$. Then $x-a=0.1$.
Suppose $x=a+0.001$. Then $x-a=0.001$ ...
In summary, we can make $x-a$ as close as we like to 0 by maiking $x$ sufficiently close to $a$.

Answer (score 1):

the value of the function in a is $0$ so you can approch “near” $0$ as much you want selecting x “near” a

that’s in a simply way the concept of limit

in this case the function is said to be “continuos” as its value f(a) coincides with the value of the limit near a

in general the concept of limit is useful to study the behavior of functions “near” points at which the function is not defined (e.g. think to f(x)=1/x near 0)

Answer (score 1):

Try saying it aloud: "The limit, as $x$ tends towards $a$, of $(x-a)$ is zero."

Recall that $a$ is a *constant* (with respect to $x$) not a variable; try the case where $a=1$:

"As $x$ tends towards $1$, $(x-1)$ tends towards zero."

Can you see how the same intuition applies for general $a$?